# Python Scrapy for grabbing table columns and rows

Tags: python

I'm relatively a noob at python and it's my first time learning scrapy. I've done data mining with perl quite successfully before, but this is a whole different ballgame!

I'm trying to scrape a table, grab the columns of each row. My code is below.

items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class Cio100Item(Item):
   company = Field()
   person = Field()
   industry = Field()
   url = Field()
```

scrape.py (the spider)

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from cio100.items import Cio100Item

items = []

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "scrape"
  allowed_domains = ["cio.co.uk"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.cio.co.uk/cio100/2013/cio/"]

def parse(self, response):
  sel = Selector(response)
  tables = sel.xpath('//table[@class="bgWhite listTable"]//h2')
  for table in tables:
    # print table
    item = Cio100Item()
    item['company'] = table.xpath('a/text()').extract()
    item['person'] = table.xpath('a/text()').extract()
    item['industry'] = table.xpath('a/text()').extract()
    item['url'] = table.xpath('a/@href').extract()
    items.append(item)
  return items
```

I'm have some trouble understanding how to articulate the xpath selection correctly.

I *think* this line is the problem:

```
      tables = sel.xpath('//table[@class="bgWhite listTable"]//h2')
```

When I run the scraper as is above the result is I get things like this in terminal:

```
2014-01-13 22:13:29-0500 [scrape] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.cio.co.uk/cio100/2013/cio/>

{'company': [u"\nDomino's Pizza\n"],
 'industry': [u"\nDomino's Pizza\n"],
 'person': [u"\nDomino's Pizza\n"],
 'url': [u'/cio100/2013/dominos-pizza/']}

2014-01-13 22:13:29-0500 [scrape] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.cio.co.uk/cio100/2013/cio/>
{'company': [u'\nColin Rees\n'],
 'industry': [u'\nColin Rees\n'],
 'person': [u'\nColin Rees\n'],
 'url': [u'/cio100/2013/dominos-pizza/']}
```

Ideally I want only one block, not two, with Domino's in the company slot, Colin in the person slot, and the industry grabbed, which it's not doing.

When I use firebug to inspect the table, I see h2 for columns 1 and 2 (company and person) but column 3 is h3?

When I modify the tables line to h3 at the end, as follows

```
      tables = sel.xpath('//table[@class="bgWhite listTable"]//h3')
```

I get this

```
2014-01-13 22:16:46-0500 [scrape] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.cio.co.uk/cio100/2013/cio/>
{'company': [u'\nRetail\n'],
 'industry': [u'\nRetail\n'],
 'person': [u'\nRetail\n'],
 'url': [u'/cio100/2013/dominos-pizza/']}
```

Here it only produces 1 block, and it's capturing Industry and the URL correctly. But it's not getting the company name or person.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as the xpath goes, consider doing something like:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.cio.co.uk/cio100/2013/cio/
...
>>> for tr in sel.xpath('//table[@class="bgWhite listTable"]/tr'):
...     item = Cio100Item()
...     item['company'] = tr.xpath('td[2]//a/text()').extract()[0].strip()
...     item['person'] = tr.xpath('td[3]//a/text()').extract()[0].strip()
...     item['industry'] = tr.xpath('td[4]//a/text()').extract()[0].strip()
...     item['url'] = tr.xpath('td[4]//a/@href').extract()[0].strip()
...     print item
... 
{'company': u'LOCOG',
 'industry': u'Leisure and entertainment',
 'person': u'Gerry Pennell',
 'url': u'/cio100/2013/locog/'}
{'company': u'Laterooms.com',
 'industry': u'Leisure and entertainment',
 'person': u'Adam Gerrard',
 'url': u'/cio100/2013/lateroomscom/'}
{'company': u'Vodafone',
 'industry': u'Communications and IT services',
 'person': u'Albert Hitchcock',
 'url': u'/cio100/2013/vodafone/'}
...
```

other than that you better `yield` items one by one rather than accumulating them in a list

Comment: Instead of calling extract and then grabbing the zeroeth item, one can call extract_first.